# Export multiple data to MS PROJECT at once - Array

Tags: excel, vba, populate, ms-project

I am trying to populate multiple lines at once on MS Project, is there a way to change the content of multiple cells at once? I was using Task.SetField, but is too slow when I have large data.

So I have tried SENDKEYS copied MS Excel (COPY and PASTE). It worked, but it is not the best solution yet.

Does Microsoft project has a way to change data at once , similary to MS Excel?

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far?